# Windows Forms app connecting to a client program to pull and display information

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, client

I'm trying to find out the best way to have a Windows Forms app (which calculates input and displays the result in a textbox after clicking a button) connect to a client program.

This client program pulls real-time data from a source. The real-time data from said source is a market. I want to add a search function in the Windows Forms app I created to pull real-time data from client program and have it displayed in a textbox and show a graph.

Microsoft's Bing AI search engine gave me an answer:
"1. Add a button to the form.
2. Add an event handler for the button click event.
3. In the event handler create a new instance of the client program.
4. Call the client program's method to pull data from the source.
5. Display the data in a textbox and show a graph. (show a graph would be a bonus for me)
`ClientProgram client = new ClientProgram();`
In the new instance do I replace "ClientProgram" syntax with the corresponding client program that I have to the actual name of the program?
Any help, direction, or hints, would be greatly appreciated.